# Calculating LookAt without applying it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to clamp the rotation of a bone while using `LookAt`.

The `LookAt` function works great, but it doesn't offer any clamp possibilities, and to my knowledge, `LookAt` doesn't provide a way seeing the resulting rotation without 
without applying it to a transform.

I would therefore like to know if it's possible to first calculate the results of `LookAt` without applying it first.

Answer (score 2):

Calculate the direction vector you need:

```
Vector3 direction = bone.transform.position - targetTransform.position;
```

Use Quaternion.LookAt to calculate the rotation you require:

```
Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.LookAt(direction);
```

Now perform any mathematics you want to perform on the supplied rotation, for example if you only want to rotate the bone a maximum of 10 degrees per second you would do this:

```
newRotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(bone.transform.rotation, newRotation, 10f * time.deltaTime);
```

Finally, apply the rotation to the bone:

```
bone.rotation = newRotation;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just apply `LookAt`, see the result and then clamp the result, applying the final rotation.

It's not uncommon to apply intermediate transforms during a frame (`update` function or similar). The important thing is that at the end of the `Update` (or `LateUpdate` or `FixedUpdate`) function the transform to be the desired one.

Comment: I have to do all this in LateUpdate. I would really like to avoid applying it just to see how it looks.

Comment: @tmighty I don't understand your reluctance to applying intermediate transforms. The fact that you use it in `LateUpdate` rather than `Update` makes no difference in this regard. Could you please elaborate on why do you think applying the transform is bad?

Comment: That would be lots of overhead. Unity would have to recalculate / update many things, eating valuable time. I hope it's ok to not accept your answer as "the" answer yet. I would really like to know if it's possible to calculate the result before having to apply it.

Comment: first, it's perfectly ok to accept or not accept any answer at your own discretion. Secondly, Unity would not recalculate or update anything until after the `LateUpdate` function finishes, so, rly the only thing that matters is the value of the transform at the end of the function.

Comment: Let's say I use the LookAt function in line 1 of my code in LateUpdate. I thought I could analyze the results in line 2 already. Does your comment mean that I can analyze the results only in the next frame?

Comment: at line 1 you use `LookAt`. At line two you compute the new clamped angle. At line 3 you apply the new transformation. In the next lines you do however many transformations you need to get to the desired result. `LateUpdate` finishes. Unity now does its thing and computes and updates what it needs to compute and update based on the new state of the program. All this in one frame.

Comment: Not uncommon where? In the land of bad programmers maybe? How exactly would you know just what calculations are performed by Unity when you set the transform, and how much overhead there'll be? You should not ever use framework API to keep your calculation's intermediate result.

Comment: @Arshia001 that's how I know Unity to work. I am interested if you know something else.

Comment: @bolov I know that *properties* are actually a pair of *methods*, and methods possibly do *calculations*, which means you could get *bad performance* if you abuse them.

Comment: @Arshia001 yeah, but as fair as I know in this case they don't anything more. I'll double check and come back with actual observations.

Comment: @bolov and can you guarantee they won't *ever* do anything?

Comment: @bolov continuously?